# Why is there a difference of execution plan people local and production version of mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `reach_growth` and i have created a query for this table to fetch data. However locally the data takes approx 30 seconds to return where as in production aws rds mysql m5.xlarge it takes 1~ second.

**schema** - The schema is the same locally and in production.

**prod**

```
CREATE TABLE `reach_growth` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reach_value` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `stat_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_date` (`date`),
  KEY `index_reach` (`reach_value`),
  KEY `index_record` (`service_type`,`service_id`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=69127328 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**local**

```
CREATE TABLE `reach_growth` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reach_value` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `stat_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_date` (`date`),
  KEY `index_reach` (`reach_value`),
  KEY `index_record` (`service_type`,`service_id`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=69051905 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**query**

```
explain SELECT `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`id`,
       `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`service_type`,
       `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`service_id`,
       `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`reach_value`,
       `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`stat_type`,
       `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`date`,
       `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`timestamp`
FROM `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`
WHERE (`checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`service_id` IN (      '124021995',
                     '1962751351',
                     '213749122',
                     '23392732',
                     '496275200462',
                     '50160915',
                     '501828146',
                     'UC5jm7vq-8YUjCYKh_JysFPw') AND
       `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`date` >= "2022-02-01" AND `checkpoint_gg`.`reach_growth`.`date` <= "2022-02-28")
```

I can see the execution plan for local and production versions are different but i don't quite understand why given taht the schema is the same.

**local execution plan**

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, reach_growth, , ALL, index_date, , , , 64258862, 25.00, Using where
```

**prod execution plan**

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, reach_growth, , range, index_date, index_date, 3, , 662026, 50.00, Using index condition; Using where
```

Can someone tell me why there is a different in the execution plan and how i can possible make my local version reflect the production version?

Comment: The schema is the same, as you say, but is the data also the same ?   Execution plans are also influenced by data.

Comment: @Luuk the production version has slightly more data, my local backup is maybe a week older.

Comment: Optimise table or use/force index can solve the problem, see the answer to the duplicate question for a lot more details. Since you have a problem in the local copy, running optimise table will not be a problem for you.